# ¿Qué tan extendido está el uso de la palabra "nequicia"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, sustantivos

[**Nequicia**](https://dle.rae.es/nequicia) figura en el Diccionario de la lengua como:

> 1. f. cult. Maldad, perversidad.

¿Qué tan extendido está su uso hoy día?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Diría que su uso es muy escaso. Personalmente, como lector, jamás me topé con ella y (a juzgar [por esta estadística de frecuencia](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=nequicia&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=32&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cnequicia%3B%2Cc0)) parece un término bastante obsoleto, cuya aplicación se refleja en escritos de principios del siglo 19

[image]

Como puede verse [en las búsquedas de google books](https://www.google.com/search?q=nequicia&client=firefox-b-d&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjVw4CJhsnsAhWyGbkGHRBKCH4Q_AUoAXoECBEQCQ&biw=1216&bih=623) la palabra aparece en resultados que corresponden a escritos de hace dos siglos